# How to send events from subtab1 to subtab2, after the subtab2 is opened?

Tags: lightning, javascript, console, subtab-apps

I want to send some parameters from one subtab to another subtab.
For example, subtab1 has a link which opens subtab2. The parameters cannot be sent in url as the parameters are too long to be sent. 
Thus we have written a post event which gets fired with an interval of 5 seconds when we click the link in subtab1. This gets captured in subtab2.

But the issue is we have to hardcode the timeout time. Is there any way to keep posting an event until it is captured and consumed and then clear the event, or is there a way to send the object in JSON format or string format from one subtab to another ?

Comment: I know it can seems ugly, but you can keep posting you event from the first page. In the second page when you are finally able to catch that event, you can post another event which signal the first tab that everything is fine

Comment: I thought of this, but as our application is way to huge to keep posting events, I am not sure if we can go ahead with this approach.

Comment: Skip the first part, have an event on page one waiting for page 2 to signal it is ready to receive the post, then send the post from tab1

Comment: please share your current code so we can try to see how you handle your requirement